# Nodewebkit vs Electron

Tags: sqlite, express, node-webkit, electron

I am researching what way to go. I need to build a good structured approach, in a way a skeleton app so other developers can start coding against it.

Requirements:
- Web application (SQL Server)
- Desktop application (Sql Lite)
- Authentication
- Same code base as much as possible
- Modular structure
- Continuous delivery

So far I was using NW as a platform. As for the frameworks, I have experimented with Sails, and unfortunately it turns out that SQLite will be a problem for the Sails. Sails uses waterline, and I cant make it work with compiled SQlite. I would love to use Sails, as I have experience with it.

Now, I am looking at NW and Express. At least I know I can make it work with SQLite.

Recently I heard about the [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/). And I have some questions regarding it.

1. Is it better approach to use it versus NW + some framework?
2. In Electron, do I also must use compiled Sqlite binaries? if the answer is no, then it seems Sails.js is plausible decision
3. What are the pitfalls of the Electron in the long run?

Any insight is appreaciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I couldn't say for Sails.js since I didn't work with it, but for direct comparison of NW.js and Electron you can read more [here](http://tangiblejs.com/posts/nw-js-electron-compared).

I've made prototype applications in both and my breakdown would be simple: difference is in Node context being available on renderer process (NW.js has it, Electron doesn't, both have their own reasons why). In my mind, Node context being available makes it easier for day-to-day development. On the other hand, Electron came a long way in 2 years (it is in the end supported by Github) and has a growing community support.

I went on Electron path, since I needed to provide easy way to update application once it is in production, and Electron makes it really easy with updater.